# Function to check if a mongoose object contain a subfield

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The following code doesn't work properly, I want to check after my mongoose findOne query if some subdocument in my object are defined.

```
function cleanIfAny(social, value) {
    var name = social + '.id';
    var query = {};
    query[name] = value;

    User.findOne(query, function (err, found) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // if the account is already linked somewhere else
        if (found) {
            // detach it from there
            found[social] = undefined;

            // TODO Check if field in document is present
            console.log(found.local + ' ' + found.google + ' ' + found.facebook);
            console.log(isEmpty(found.local)+ ' ' + isEmpty(found.google) + ' ' + isEmpty(found.facebook));
            if( isEmpty(found.local) && isEmpty(found.google) && isEmpty(found.facebook) ) {
                console.log('no more account attached deleting');
                found.remove();
            } else {
                console.log('ok unlink the account');
                found.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                })
            }
        }

    })
}

function isEmpty(obj) {
    return (obj == null || Object.keys(obj).length === 0);
}
```

This code return

```
{} { token: 'abcdefgh, name: 'FirstName LastName', id: '123456789', email: 'myemail@gmail.com' } undefined
false false false
ok unlink the account
```

Instead of this

```
true false true
```

However I have tried my function outside of this scope with some simple variables and everything work as expected with my isEmpty() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you a lot:

https://lodash.com/docs#isEmpty

Save you reinventing the wheel all the time.

Comment: I just tried with lodash the result is the same inside my function :o
Maybe the format return by mongoose isn't what I'm expect or something is bad in the whole function.

Comment: In my case the typeof found, found.local, found.google and found.facebook are objects even the undefined

Comment: mongoose documents have a `_doc` property where the actual mongo object is stored. The key isn't top level. I think checking `doc.property === undefined` should work.

Comment: Seems that using found.google.id (not the object itself but one variable inside my model) does the trick but I don't really understand why

Comment: try doing `found = found.toObject()` before doing those checks. I have a suspicion it's mongoose playing tricks.